# Erb in Javascript causes error on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

In my file views/posts/new.html.erb, I have a script at the bottom:

```
 $('div #mainPhotoDropzone').dropzone({
        url: "/photos?post_id=" + $("#post_form").data('post-id'),
        complete: function(file){
          var url = "<%= @post.photos.first.file.path %>";
          $.get(url, function(data){
            $('#mainPhotoDropzone').attr('style', "background-image: url('" + data.main_photo + "')");
          })
         }
```

I get an error on page load since `@post.photos.first` doesn't existe yet. This is supposed to be triggered when the upload is complete, so when the file exist.

How can I avoid this error ? I don't understand why this is executed on page load when I defined it on "complete" event and I don't see an alternative.

Comment: Your markup is rendered before any of the JS runs.

Comment: @elclanrs but this isn't part of the actual markup, it's a script at the bottom ... How could I avoid this error and still use this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside `<% ... %>` is executed before the javascript is sent to the client. The javascript is generated, the`<%= %>` tags are replaced with the result of running the code inside of them. So if you have for example:

```
I am <%= "super "*5 %>awesome.
```

What the browser sees is:

```
I am super super super super super awesome
```

Because the code `"super "*5` has *already been run*.

Comment: thanks for your help ! How can I avoid this error but keep a similar function ?

Comment: The answer is complicated, you'll probably want to ask a separate question.